# Transferring simple array of results through NETLink

Tags: .netlink

Further to Todd Gayley's 2006 reply to the question [.NET / hand over of variables](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2006/Aug/msg00122.html), I am trying to fill an array of doubles with values via NET/Link.  However, I am getting an exception.  Can anyone help?

```
MathKernel k = new MathKernel();
k.ResultFormat = MathKernel.ResultFormatType.Expr;
k.Compute("RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0.02, 0.10], 51]");
var mathErgebnis = (Expr) k.Result;
Array exprarray = mathErgebnis.AsArray(ExpressionType.Real, 2);
double[] ra = new double[51];
for (int m = 0; m < 51; m++)
    ra[m] = (double) exprarray.GetValue(m);
```

Debug shows the result (Ergebnis) is being computed ok.

[image]

Some details of the var object.

[image]

An exception is generated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solution by way of a work-around.  Converted everything to strings.

```
MathKernel k = new MathKernel();

k.Compute("StringTake[ToString[FortranForm[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0.02, 0.10], 51]]], {6, -2}]");

string mathErgebnis = k.Result.ToString();

List<string> myList = mathErgebnis.Split(',').ToList();

List<double> result = myList.Select(x => double.Parse(x)).ToList();

double[] ra = result.ToArray();

k.Dispose();
```